# Retrieving datas from partitioned table - MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning, explain

I've one generic question regarding retrieving datas from an partitioned table (MySQL Database).

I've Partitioned by Year range in the table.Also i've indexed the partitioned column.

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(`RDATE`))
(PARTITION pp0 VALUES LESS THAN (0) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2005) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2008) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2010) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2011) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (2012) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (2013) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (2014) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = MyISAM) */
```

while running the query below..

```
explain partitions select Products from salesdata where rdate between '2011-11-01' and LAST_DAY('2011-11-01')
```

the result is like (total rows 2502 scanned..)

```
id    select_type    table      partitions    type     possible_keys    key      key_len    ref    rows    Extra      
1     SIMPLE         sldata    p5            range    sls_ind     sls_ind    3                 2502    Using where
```

But if i run this query..

```
 explain partitions select Products from salesdata where rdate between '2011-12-01' and LAST_DAY('2011-12-01')
```

the result is (total rows 55181 scanned..)

```
id    select_type    table      partitions    type    possible_keys    key    key_len    ref    rows     Extra      
1     SIMPLE         sldata    p5            ALL     sls_ind                              55181    Using where
```

Anyone have an idea,   why that second query scans the whole partition unlike the first query..?

Comment: You posted the same query twice, was that intended?

Comment: Ok, nevermind my question. I was not looking for the year.